# EF6 MySql - All parts of a key must be non-nullable

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-6

So this is a new error that just start coming up for me and I'm not sure why.  When I try to add a table through EF6, I get the following errors on any fields that are non-nullable.   On tables that I have been able to add, if I open the edmx file in XML, I can see that the [Key] section for each table in the StorageSection contains every field in the table.  So this is clearly a bug somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

I've done the following:
- Double-checked my data model in MySql (using version 5.7.7)
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2015 
- Uninstalled and reinstalled Entity Framework (version 6.1.3)
- Using the Devart dotConnect MySql Pro Trial (version 8.6.677.0)
- Double-checked all web.config options to make sure they are correct.

Sample Error:
Error 13101: Key part 'LockOutEndDateUtc' for type 'aspnetusers' is not valid. All parts of the key must be non-nullable.   HRSMonitor  C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HRSMonitor\HRSMonitor\Models\dbHRS.edmx

Here's the create table script for the aspnetusers table:

'aspnetusers', 'CREATE TABLE `aspnetusers` (  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,  `PasswordHash` varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,  `SecurityStamp` varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,  `PhoneNumber` varchar(21000) DEFAULT NULL,  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,  `LockOutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,  `LockoutEnabled` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,  `UserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),  KEY `Id` (`Id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have this table already created? Meaning (your question is vague) does the table physically exist already?

Comment: Yes, the table is already created.  This is for a model-first design.

Comment: `show create table theTableName;`  <--- run that, publish it with an [edit] to question (ie: don't dump it in a comment down here)

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem, in MySql, the following statements need to be run and then EF6 cooperates:

set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';
set optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off';